# Query for retrieving limited records for a single page of grid

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, query-optimization, sql-server-2017

I want to fill my grid using a SQL Server procedure which retrieves data from multiple tables. I have done as much as I could to optimize my query and speed up delivering data from database to the page. Currently I am using below query which returns 50 of 1500 records in about 8 seconds.

It would be appreciated if anyone can suggest any edit to make my query return the required resul faster.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[LoadPCIList]
@iduser int  , @page int  , @pagesize int  , @filters nvarchar(max), @sortcolumn nvarchar(max) , @sortdirection nvarchar(4) , @sorttype nvarchar(7)
as

declare 
    @idpci nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @no nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @pcino nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @pono nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @blno nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @customer nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @pcidate nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @pcidateshamsi nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @vchtype nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @commodity nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @qty nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @amountpci nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @currencypci nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @rate nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @amountpi nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @currencypi nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @settled nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @remained nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @thirdparty nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @step nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @workflow nvarchar(max) = null , 
    @issuer nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @fileqty nvarchar(max) = null ,
    @note nvarchar(max) = null 
    select 
        @idpci = idpci ,
        @no = no,
        @pcino = pcino  ,
        @pono = pono  ,
        @blno = blno  ,
        @customer = customer ,
        @pcidate  = pcidate ,
        @pcidateshamsi = pcidateshamsi ,
        @vchtype = vchtype ,
        @commodity = commodity ,
        @qty = qty ,
        @amountpci = amountpci ,
        @currencypci = currencypci ,
        @rate = rate,
        @amountpi = amountpi ,
        @currencypi = currencypi ,
        @settled = settled ,
        @remained = remained ,
        @thirdparty = thirdparty ,
        @step = step ,
        @workflow = workflow ,  
        @issuer = issuer , 
        @fileqty = fileqty , 
        @note = note
    FROM OPENJSON(@filters)  
         WITH (idpci nvarchar(max) 'strict $.idpci', 
               no nvarchar(max) 'strict $.no',
               pcino nvarchar(max) 'strict $.pcino',
               pono nvarchar(max) 'strict $.pono',
               blno nvarchar(max) 'strict $.blno',
               customer nvarchar(max) 'strict $.customer',
               pcidate nvarchar(max) 'strict $.pcidate',
               pcidateshamsi nvarchar(max) 'strict $.pcidateshamsi',
               vchtype nvarchar(max) 'strict $.vchtype',
               commodity nvarchar(max) 'strict $.commodity',
               qty nvarchar(max) 'strict $.qty',
               amountpci nvarchar(max) 'strict $.amountpci',
               currencypci nvarchar(max) 'strict $.currencypci',
               rate nvarchar(max) 'strict $.rate',
               amountpi nvarchar(max) 'strict $.amountpi',
               currencypi nvarchar(max) 'strict $.currencypi',
               settled nvarchar(max) 'strict $.settled',
               remained nvarchar(max) 'strict $.remained',
               thirdparty nvarchar(max) 'strict $.thirdparty',
               step nvarchar(max) 'strict $.step' , 
               workflow nvarchar(max) 'strict $.workflow',
               issuer nvarchar(max) 'strict $.issuer',
               fileqty nvarchar(max) 'strict $.fileqty' , 
               note nvarchar(max) 'strict $.note'
         )  

select * into #temp from (
select 
    a.IdPci , 
    a.No, 
    a.PciNo, 
    a.PoNo,
    a.BlNo,
    c.Title as Customer , 
    a.PciDate , 
    a.PciDateShamsi ,
    b.VchType, 
    a.Commodity , 
    a.Qty , 
    Format(a.Amount , 'N2') as AmountPci , 
    d.Abr as CurrencyPci ,
    a.Rate , 
    Format(a.Amount / a.Rate, 'N2')  as AmountPi , 
    e.Abr as CurrencyPi ,
    Format(a.Settled, 'N2')  as Settled , 
    Format(a.Remained, 'N2')  as Remained , 
    i.Title as ThirdParty ,
    g.Title as Step ,
    h.IdWorkflow ,
    h.Title as Workflow , 
    (select top(1) y.UserName from history as x inner join users as y on x.IdUser = y.IdUser  where IdForm = 117 and idvch = a.idpci ) as Issuer,
    (select count(idattachment) from attachment where idform = 117 and idvch = a.idpci ) as FileQty , 
    a.Note ,
    a.State
from PCI as a 
left join pi as b on a.idpi = b.idpi 
left join DL as c on b.IdCustomer = c.iddl 
left join Currency as d on a.IdCur = d.IdCur
left join Currency as e on b.IdCur = e.IdCur
left join FM_Steps as g on a.IdStep = g.IdStep
left join FM_Workflow as h on a.IdWorkFlow = h.IdWorkflow
left join dl as i on a.IdTrusteeAccount = i.IdDl 



where isnull(a.state,0) <> -1 
and (@idpci  ='' or cast(a.IdPci as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@idpci+'%')
and (@no  ='' or cast(a.No as nvarchar(max))  like '%'+@no+'%')
and (@pcino ='' or a.pcino like '%'+@pcino+'%')
and (@pono ='' or a.pono like '%'+@pono+'%')
and (@blno ='' or a.blno like '%'+@blno+'%')
and (@customer ='' or c.Title like '%'+@customer+'%')
and (@pcidate  ='' or cast(a.pcidate as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@pcidate+'%')
and (@pcidateshamsi  ='' or a.PciDateShamsi like '%'+@pcidateshamsi+'%')
and (@vchtype  ='' or isnull(b.VchType,'') like '%'+@vchtype+'%')
and (@commodity  ='' or a.Commodity like '%'+@commodity+'%')
and (@qty  ='' or cast(a.Qty as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@qty+'%')
and (@amountpci  ='' or cast(a.amount as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@amountpci+'%')
and (@currencypci  ='' or cast(d.Abr as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@currencypci+'%')
and (@rate  ='' or d.Title like '%'+@rate+'%')
and (@amountpi  ='' or cast(a.amount * a.Rate as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@amountpi+'%')
and (@currencypi  ='' or cast(e.Abr as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@currencypi+'%')
and (@settled  ='' or cast(a.Settled as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@settled+'%')
and (@remained  ='' or cast(a.remained as nvarchar(max)) like '%'+@remained+'%')
and (@thirdparty ='' or i.Title like '%'+@thirdparty+'%')
and (@step ='' or g.Title like '%'+@step+'%')
and (@workflow  ='' or h.Title like '%'+@workflow+'%')
and (@issuer  ='' or (select top(1) y.UserName from history as x inner join users as y on x.IdUser = y.IdUser  where IdForm = 116 and idvch = a.idpci ) like '%'+@issuer+'%')
and (@fileqty  ='' or (select cast(count(idattachment) as nvarchar(3)) from attachment where idform = 115 and idvch = a.idpci ) like '%'+@fileqty+'%')
and (@note  ='' or a.note like '%'+@note+'%')
)s

declare @totalrowscount int = (select count(idpci) from #temp)


declare @totalpagescount int = floor(@totalrowscount / @pagesize)
if(@totalrowscount % @pagesize >=1 )
    set @totalpagescount = @totalpagescount + 1 
if(@totalrowscount  = 0 )
    set @totalpagescount =  1 ;

if(@page > @totalpagescount)
    set @page = @totalpagescount ;

select cast ((
select 
    (@totalrowscount) as Qty, 
    (select * from #temp order by 
        case when @sortdirection = 'asc' and @sorttype = 'numeric'  then 
            case when  @sortcolumn = 'colIdPci' then IdPci  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colNo' then No
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colFileQty' then FileQty
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colQty' then Qty  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colAmountPci' then AmountPci  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colRate' then Rate
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colAmountPi' then AmountPi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colSettled' then Settled  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colRemained' then Remained  
            end
            else 1 
        end asc, 
        case when @sortdirection = 'asc' and @sorttype = ''  then 
            case when  @sortcolumn = 'colPciNo' then PciNo  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colPoNo' then PoNo  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCustomer' then Customer 
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colPciDate' then PciDateShamsi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colPciDateShamsi' then PciDateShamsi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCommodity' then Commodity  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colVchType' then VchType  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCurrencyPci' then CurrencyPci  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCurrencyPi' then CurrencyPi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colThirdParty' then ThirdParty  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colStep' then Step  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colWorkflow' then Workflow  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colIssuer' then Issuer  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colNote' then Note  
            end 
            else '' 
        end asc , 
        case when @sortdirection = 'desc' and @sorttype = 'numeric'  then 
            case when  @sortcolumn = 'colIdPci' then IdPci  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colNo' then No
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colFileQty' then FileQty
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colQty' then Qty  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colAmountPci' then AmountPci  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colRate' then Rate
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colAmountPi' then AmountPi   
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colSettled' then Settled  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colRemained' then Remained  
            end 
            else 1
        end desc, 
        case when @sortdirection = 'desc' and @sorttype = ''  then 
            case when  @sortcolumn = 'colPciNo' then PciNo  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colPoNo' then PoNo  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCustomer' then Customer 
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colPciDate' then PciDateShamsi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colPciDateShamsi' then PciDateShamsi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCommodity' then Commodity  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colVchType' then VchType  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCurrencyPci' then CurrencyPci  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colCurrencyPi' then CurrencyPi  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colThirdParty' then ThirdParty  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colStep' then Step  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colWorkflow' then Workflow  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colIssuer' then Issuer  
                 when  @sortcolumn = 'colNote' then Note  
            end 
            else '' 
        end desc 
     offset (@page-1)*@pagesize rows fetch next @pagesize rows only for json auto , include_null_values ) as PCIs
from setting for json auto , include_null_values) as nvarchar(max))

drop table #temp
```

Comment: *"I have done as much as I could to optimize my query"* A quick look at that query suggests not. The first clause stats with an `ISNULL`, which immediately says it hasn't been optimised (as `ISNULL` isn't SARGable). You also have 10's of leading wildcards; which will tank the performance. You also `CAST` loads of your columns to an `nvarchar(MAX)`, which you would never do in a query that has been optimised. Plus joining on a `(MAX)` is slow. Finally the initial query is a "catch-all" or "kitchen-sink" query and you make use of either `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or (well parametrised) Dynamic SQL.

Comment: On a separate note, I don't spell "PCI" with an "a", nor "FM_Steps" with a "g", and "Currency" does *not* start with an e. Use *proper* and **sensible** aliases for your objects. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)